# PHP and MySQL to populate table from unknown ID

Tags: php, mysql, populate

I have three tables: unitpost, file, and postfile with postfile being the table that links files to a particular post.

I have created a script that uploads the files and posts however I need to populate the postfile table with both the unitpostID and fileID, however once the file is uploaded, the ID is chosen at random. How can I then populate the postfile table with the fileID that was just uploaded?

Hope this made sense!!

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any code to start with? What have you came up with so far?

Comment: By *random* you mean `auto_increment`? Or really random?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) to obtain id of last insert operation.

Comment: How can I do this for two tables?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`AUTOINCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) for the primary keys, thus the IDs won't be random, and you will be able to use them either from MySQL or from PHP.

Afterwards use [`mysqli_insert_id()`](http://php.net/manual/ro/mysqli.insert-id.php) (or [`PDO::lastInsertId`](http://php.net/manual/ro/pdo.lastinsertid.php) if you use PDO) from php to get the last insert id, or, as @Nelson stated, the MySQL function directly.